# Query Failed You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, database, crud

I have this problem updating content into database. error is :

> Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'post_content = 'kjgljkkjhklj  ', post_image =
>   '45739895_2381062595269282_8123898' at line 1

this is my whole code:

```
if (isset($_GET['p_id'])) {
    $the_post_id = $_GET['p_id'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $the_post_id";
$select_posts_by_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts_by_id)) {
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_author = $row['post_author'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_category_id = $row['post_category_id'];
    $post_status = $row['post_status'];
    $post_image = $row['post_image'];
    $post_content = $row['post_content'];
    $post_tags = $row['post_tags'];
    $post_comment = $row['post_comment_count'];
    $post_date = $row['post_date'];
}


// if update post button is clicked
if (isset($_POST['update_post'])) {

    $post_author = $_POST['post_author'];
    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
    $post_category_id = $_POST['post_category'];
    $post_status = $_POST['post_status'];
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];


    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/{$post_image}");

    if (empty($post_image)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $the_post_id ";

    }

    $query = "UPDATE posts SET ";
    $query .= "post_title = '{$post_title}', ";
    $query .= "post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', ";
    $query .= "post_date = now(), ";
    $query .= "post_author = '{$post_author}', ";
    $query .= "post_status = '{$post_status}', ";
    $query .= "post_tags = '{$post_tags}' ";
    $query .= "post_content = '{$post_content}', ";
    $query .= "post_image = '{$post_image}' ";
    $query .= "WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id}"; // this is from the get request


    $update_post = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    confirmQuery($update_post);

}
```

this is the form below:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Title</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $post_title; ?>" type="text" name="post_title" class="form-control" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_category">Post Categories</label>
        <select name="post_category" id="" class="form-control form-control-md">
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
                $select_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                confirmQuery($select_categories); // this is from functions.php

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories)) {
                        $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
                        $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

                        echo "<option value='{$cat_id}'>{$cat_title}</option>";
                    }   
             ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="author">Post Author</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $post_author; ?>" type="text" name="post_author" class="form-control" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_status">Post Status</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $post_status; ?>" type="text" name="post_status" class="form-control" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Post Image</label>
        <img width="100px" src="../images/<?php echo $post_image; ?>">
        <input type="file" name="image" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_tags">Post Tags</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $post_tags; ?>" type="text" name="post_tags" class="form-control" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_content">Post Content</label> 
        <textarea name="post_content" class="form-control" id="" cols="30" rows="10" required="true">
            <?php echo $post_content; ?>
        </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="update_post" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Post">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're SQL code is missing a , after post_tags and post_image values.

Comment: @Jarzon yes, and no, that is no comma for after  post_image as the WHERE is next

Comment: This is open to SQL injections. Parameterize.

Comment: so what code is missing? can you be specific on which code should be added? thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I find this easier to read:

```
$query = "
UPDATE posts 
   SET post_title = '$post_title'
     , post_category_id = '$post_category_id'
     , post_date = now()
     , post_author = '$post_author'
     , post_status = '$post_status'
     , post_tags = '$post_tags'
     , post_content = '$post_content'
     , post_image = '$post_image'
 WHERE post_id = $the_post_id;
";
```

...but it's vital also to replace those strings with a properly parametrised query

Answer (score 0):

try replace

```
$query .= "WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id}";
```

with

```
$query .= "WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id} ";
```

That should do the magic.